# Element set doesn't have required attribute layout_height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The **LinearLayout** tag complain

> 'layout_height' attribute should be defined
>  
>   'layout_width' attribute should be defined

This is my **alpha_anim.xml**:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="200%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:zAdjustment="top"/>

   </set>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you put it in the `layout/` directory instead of the `anim/` directory?

Comment: Are you sure that it's this file that causes the problem? It doesn't look wrong.
The error should come from one of your layouts, not from an animation.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the `res/anim/` folder. Create if it doesn't exist.
Should also work in the `res/drawable/` folder.

Comment: i moved the xml file to res/anim and it worked. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that this element isn´t a layout, is an animation, you must create (if it doesn´t exist) the folder `/anim` (inside `/res`) and then place the file inside.

[image]